# Security Exception While upgrading play services version

Tags: android

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.grofers.customerapp'.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzv$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf.zzh(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzi.zzg(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzk.zzn(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzwZ(Unknown Source:1000)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zze.zzxa(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
```

Getting above exception in Fabric while after updating play services version.

Comment: Getting this as well, did you ever resolve?